# How do I delete an ECS capacity provider which is in-use?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

I'm using CDK to set up an application backed by ECS.  My stack is created successfully, but when I run `cdk destroy` the tear-down fails with the following error:

```
7:06:03 AM | DELETE_FAILED        | AWS::ECS::ClusterCapacityProviderAssociations | sd-cluster/sd-cluster
Resource handler returned message: "The specified capacity provider is in use and cannot be removed. (Service: AmazonECS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ResourceInUseException; Request ID:
f76555d1-5dc0-47b7-ba65-b65529c8b999; Proxy: null)" (RequestToken: 00531a51-2d95-aef9-77cd-3e06714c78b3, HandlerErrorCode: null)
```

I would assume obviously this is because my capacity provider is backed by an ASG (autoscaling group) which has an instance running, and there is a task currently running in my cluster.

The ASG is also defined within the stack.

But then how can I tear down this stack without manually going to the console and setting the running instances to zero?

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue in CDK - [here's the issue on GitHub](https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/19275).

I included a workaround in the comments, here it is in Python:

```py
@jsii.implements(cdk.IAspect)
class HotfixCapacityProviderDependencies:
    # Add a dependency from capacity provider association to the cluster
    # and from each service to the capacity provider association
    def visit(self, node: IConstruct) -> None:
        if type(node) is ecs.Ec2Service:
            children = node.cluster.node.find_all()
            for child in children:
                if type(child) is ecs.CfnClusterCapacityProviderAssociations:
                    child.node.add_dependency(node.cluster)
                    node.node.add_dependency(child)
```

You would use it just as any other aspect:

```py
# in the stack
Aspects.of(self).add(HotfixCapacityProviderDependencies())
```